# How to connect mongo compass to aws ec2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect mongo compass to aws ec2 instance db , which is throwing me an error 
"Mongodb not running on the provided host and port"

I tried by adding ip to bindip variable in "mongod.conf" file.
                          Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is usually whitelist/firewall setting that disallows connection from the outside world. Also make sure your bindip setting is correct.

Comment: #network interfaces
net :
    port : 27017
   bindIp : 127.0.0.1, xx.xx.xx.xx (my ip)
these are changes done in mongod.conf file

Comment: Check whether your ec2 security setting allows connection from outside

Comment: Does this work for you - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/02/05/connect-to-remote-mongodb-on-aws-ec2-simply-and-securely-via-ssh-tunnel

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure bind ip is set to 0.0.0.0
2. Make sure security group with port 27017 (your mongodb port) is added in your EC2 instance's security groups